# Convergence of eigenvalues for sequence of compressions of a compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, compact-operators

Suppose $H$ is a separable Hilbert space, $A$ is a Hilbert Schmidt operator on $H$, and $P_n$ is an increasing sequence of finite rank orthogonal projections of $H$ (so $P_nx\rightarrow x$ for all $x\in H$).  Then we certainly have that, for $A_n=P_nAP_n$, $A_n\rightarrow A$ in the Hilbert-Schmidt norm; see for example this very complete post on [Approximating a Hilbert-Schmidt operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373014/approximating-a-hilbert-schmidt-operator).  My follow-up question: If the singular values of an operator are always ordered from largest to smallest, including multiplicities, is it (trivially?) true that the $k^\mathrm{th}$ singular value of the the sequence of operators $\{A_n\}_{n\ge k}$ converges to the $k^\mathrm{th}$ singular value of $A$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  By the [max-min principle for singular values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Min-max_principle_for_singular_values), 
$$\sigma_k(A)=\sup_{\dim S=k}\min \{\|Ax\|/\|x\|:x\in S\} \tag1$$ 
It follows that 
$$
\begin{split}\sigma_k(A_n) &=\sup_{\dim S=k}\min \{\|P_nAP_nx\|/\|x\|:x\in S\} \\
&\le \sup_{\dim S=k}\min \{\|Ay\|/\|y\|:x\in P_n S\}  \\ &\le \sigma_k(A)
\end{split} \tag2$$ 
In the reverse direction, pick a subspace $S$ such that $\dim S=k$ and $\min \{\|Ax\|/\|x\|:x\in S\} > \sigma_k(A)-\epsilon$. Show* that the restriction of $A-A_n$ to the unit sphere of $S$ tends to zero uniformly. Conclude that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \sigma_k(A_n) \ge \sigma_k(A)$, finishing the proof.

(*) One way to do this is to pick a finite $\epsilon$-net $E$ in the unit sphere of $S$ and find $N$ such that $\|Ax-A_n x\|<\epsilon $ for all $x\in E$ and $n\ge N$. Then use the uniform boundedness  boundedness of $\|A_n\|$.

Comment: The nice thing being that the sv max-min theorem is true in general for compact operators in $B(H)$. +1.